# Assigning new IP to a VM each time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

On GCP, I want to change external IP address of my VM instance several times in a day and in my project VM needs to be assigned new IP address each time. However, regardless of using ephemeral or static IP, when I try to change IP, there are only 3 or 4 different IP addresses. After 4 times change, the loop backs to start so the IP has been assigned before was assigned to VM again.

Is there a way to assign a new IP address to VM each time?

Comment: What is your thinking on why you would want to change the public IP address of your Compute Engine?  Might you be trying to solve the wrong problem?

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario you can use [protocol forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding) in order to assign multiple/different external IP addresses to a VM instance. Then When traffic is sent to an external IP address that is served by a forwarding rule, the forwarding rule directs that traffic to the corresponding target pool or target instances.

As per [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding#forwardingrules) you can create up to 50 forwarding rule objects per project.

Answer (score 0):

I think (don't know) that this isn't possible.

You are being loaned public IPs from Google's pool and, technically these are assigned randomly (you won't always get these IPs) but, over the timeframe you've monitored, you detect there's a pattern and the behavior is insufficient for your needs.

It's unclear why you need random IPs -- I assume random DNS naming won't suffice for your use-case -- you may want to submit a feature request to Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Given that you detect a period of 3-4 IPs, you could temporarily hold these on VM interfaces and, once you obtain a different IP for your app, you could release the others?